# Can someone explain differences of Test-Driven Development, Agile Development, SCRUM & Unit Testing

Tags: testing, tdd

And further, how they relate together or even if they do?
What would one do to understand the various pieces to a simple question, how to I properly build a testing facility for my (web or other) application?

Comment: Fully defining this grab-bag of terminology, as well as designing an automated testing strategy for you, is far too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Possibly, I wasn't sure how to make the question more concise without being broad but specific to the various testing lingo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Agile Development** is a banner term for many things, too numerous to mention, including Scrum and TDD. It typically, but not always follows the [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/).

**SCRUM**
This is a particular flavour of agile. This diagram from wikipedia shows the process:

[image]

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)) for more info.

**Unit Testing**
This is the art of writing code that tests code. Failing tests indicate a problem in your solution.

**Test Driven Development**
This is the practice of writing tests before code, some of the advantages being that untested code isn't added to the solution, and that the code written is testable.

A ***proper testing facility***, usually leverages something along the lines of xunit, junit, nunit, mstest depending on the framework used, these tests are typically ran via a Continuous Integration build on some kind of build server. That is a build that runs everytime the code changes, that executes tests. This way problems are identified quicker.